# Create randomly an undirected connected graph using Matlab

Tags: graphs, matlab

I want to create randomly an undirected connected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges using Matlab. How can I do this?

Comment: That depends on the properties and probability distributions you want the random graphs to possess. Random googling provides many links, such as https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/297615-how-to-generate-random-graph-of-n-vertices-with-random-connections-in-matlab , https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4206-erdos-renyi-random-graph, and https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45564-how-to-create-random-graph-of-n-vertices-with-c-fixed-neighbours-in-matlab to get you started.